# minipage right margin

Tags: margins, indentation, minipage

I want to start a minipage, with the regular left-indentation, but to have its right margin adjusted with regular page right margin.
An example of discrepancy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
    \noindent\emph{Here is the regular text:}
    \par\smallskip\noindent
    \blindtext

    \par\medskip

    \noindent\emph{And here is the minipage:}
    \par\smallskip

    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \blindtext
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[**eTeX-Solution**](http://ctan.org/pkg/etex/)

Use

```
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-\parindent\relax}
```

to subtract the regular indentation.

At this point I want to post the comment of [Martin Scharrer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975/martin-scharrer):

> `\dimexpr` awaits the expression directly without the square
>   brackets`{ }`. It is a lower level (e-)TeX primitive, not a LaTeX
>   macro. The `\relax` terminates the expression explicitly. It might
>   work without it, but otherwise you have the risk that `\dimexpr` takes
>   also some code following the expression inside the environment or
>   macro as part of the expression.

[**package `calc`**](http://ctan.org/pkg/calc/)

Use

```
\usepackage{calc}
 ...
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth-\parindent}
```

to subtract the regular indentation.

**LaTeX**

Use

```
\newlength{\mywidth}
\setlength{\mywidth}{\textwidth}
\addtolength{\mywidth}{-\parindent}
 ...
\begin{minipage}{\mywidth}
```

to subtract the regular indentation.

**TeX**

Use

```
\newdimen\mywidth
\mywidth=\textwidth
\advance\mywidth by-\parindent
 ...
\begin{minipage}{\mywidth}
```

to subtract the regular indentation.

Comment: Thanks :-) I understand that \dimexpr enables to write length expressions after it. Shouldn't it have {}, like \dimexpr{\textwidth-\parindent}? and what does the ``relax'' do?

Comment: @Andro: No, `\dimexpr` awaits the expression directly without the `{ }`. It is a lower level (e-)TeX primitive, not a LaTeX macro. The `\relax` terminates the expression explicitly. It might work without it, but otherwise you have the risk that `\dimexpr` takes also some code following the expression inside the environment or macro as part of the expression.